# Changing tuple to lowercase - specific situation (Python; NLTK)

Tags: python, tuples, nltk, lowercase

I am using Python and NLTK and trying to change the Brown Corpus into lowercase.

In particular, my goal is to tag a wordlist with each word's most likely part-of-speech (e.g., "Christmas" is a noun). However, my word list contains all lower-case words ("christmas"). Thus, some words are not identified because the cases mismatch.

The tuples in brown.tagged_sents() look like this:

```
[[(u'The', u'AT'), (u'Fulton', u'NP-TL'), (u'County', u'NN-TL'),...
```

I have tried the following code:

```
brown_sents = brown.tagged_sents()
brown_sentslower = [[x.lower() for x in element] for element in brown_sents]
```

But have still received the error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I successfully replicated the results from another answer ([Python: Using lower function on tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463826/python-using-lower-function-on-tuples)), but I wonder if there is something special about using this code with brown.tagged_sents().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lowercase the elements *in* the tuple:

```
brown_sentslower = [[(word.lower(), tag.lower()) for word, tag in element]
                    for element in brown_sents]
```

Note that I used tuple unpacking in the `for` loop there; each `(word, tag)` pair is unpacked into the `word` and `tag` variables, so you can address them individually. The loop then produces a *new* tuple with the lowercased versions of these two values.

This assumes that you want both the word *and* the tag to be lowercased; e.g. `(u'Fulton', u'NP-TL')` becomes `(u'fulton', u'np-tl')`.

If only the word should be lowercased, replace `tag.lower()` with `tag`:

```
brown_sentslower = [[(word.lower(), tag) for word, tag in element]
                    for element in brown_sents]
```